# How to detect if two turtles are near each other or touch each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

So I am trying to make a snake game in python, and i reached the point where the snake has to eat the fruit / point to grow. So to do that I made two turtles. One is the snake's head and one is the fruit that has to be eaten. Except I don't know how to make it so when the snake head turtle touches the fruit the fruit will randomly go to another location.
Here's the code I have so far:

```
import turtle
import random
import time

points = 0
game_over = False

# Create map
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Create turtles :)
snake = turtle.Turtle()
snake.color('white')
snake.penup()

point_master = turtle.Turtle()
point_master.color('white')
point_master.penup()


snake.penup()

# Code snake so it can move :D
snake_speed = 2

def travel():
    snake.forward(snake_speed)
    screen.ontimer(travel, 10)

screen.onkey(lambda: snake.setheading(90), 'Up')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.setheading(180), 'Left')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.setheading(0), 'Right')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.setheading(270), 'Down')

# Here is where we code it so when the snake touches the fruit the fruit will relocate.



# Continues to make snake move :)
screen.listen()
travel()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, do you know how to determine the turtle's position? Do you know how to determine the distance between two points? What is the actual *question* you have?

Comment: I can determine the turtle's position. I've tried something like this:

snake.distance(point_master) < 15:
    x = random.randint(-250, 250)
    y = random.randint(-250, 250)
    point_master.goto(x, y)

Comment: "I've tried something like this: snake.distance(point_master) < 15:" Okay, and what happened when you tried it? What is the actual difficulty you are having?

Comment: When I run it and go through the fruit it doesn't do anything

Comment: Okay, did you try checking what `snake.distance(point_master)` returns, at the point that the snake is close enough to the fruit? Did you try checking that it actually gets called?

Comment: So I just added a print statement under 'snake.distance(point_master) and it didn't print anything. So I'm pretty sure it's not being called.

Answer (score 1):

In turtle we have `xcor()`, `ycor()`, `setx()` and `sety()`.

`xcor()` finds where is the object(in this case it can be your snake or the food ) on x axis.

`ycor()` is the same but it finds the location on y axis.

`setx()` you move the x axis

Example:

```
if .......: 
    turtle.setx(-20)
```

this means if .... happens turtle will go -20 in x axis

Same in `sety()` the difference is the turtle will go in y axis

In your case you can do something like this

```
xy=random.randint(0,100)
food = turtle.Turtle()
food.goto(10, 50)

#lets say that in first level it will start on 10,50 cordinates

if snake.xcor == food.xcor and snake.ycor == food.xcor:
    food.goto(xy, xy)

#xy was the random number between 0-100    
#for setx() and sety() you can use it on your key bindings
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can surround code with back-ticks ` (one for an in-line element, or groups of three for a block) to format code in your post, which will make it a lot clearer!